# Angular - Waiting for a token value from Session Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, ecmascript-6, bearer-token

I am using Angular 2.0 to write a custom HTTP Provider which allows me to attach a bearer token to each HTTP Request to the API. This is essentially what [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) does, but I can not use that library in my application.

The problem is this - before I make a call to my HTTP API, I need to wait unit both tokens are present in session storage. Once I have both, I can then send the request.

My HTTP Client class looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

function getWindow(): any {
  return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  private _window: Window;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    let keys = sessionStorage.getItem("adal.token.keys").split("|");

    let key1 = keys[0]; // web
    let key2 = keys[1]; // api

    if (!key1 || !key2) {
      // I NEED TO WAIT FOR BOTH KEYS!
    }

    let accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("adal.access.token.key" + key2);
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  }

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }

  post(url, data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post(url, data, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid using a Timer (setTimeout) for obvious reasons. I would like to use an ES6 promise type of thing.

Comment: One way to solve this problem would be to use BehaviourSubject of  'rxjs'. Did you try with that?

Comment: *wait unit both tokens are present in session storage* - no code is provided for the place where they are set.

Comment: They are set in an AngularJS section of the app using ADAL JS. I can't use ADAL in NG2, so I am forced to roll out my own solution. However, I can have access to the session storage tokens.